# Generalized semilattice morphism

Tags: terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders

Join-semilattice morphism from a join-semilattice $\mathfrak{A}$ to a join-semilattice $\mathfrak{B}$ is a function $\alpha$ conforming to the formula $\alpha(X\sqcup Y) = \alpha X\sqcup\alpha Y$ (where $\sqcup$ denotes the semilattice operations).

Equivalently transforming this formula (under the supposition that $\alpha$ is a monotone function), we get:
$\alpha (X \sqcup Y) \sqsubseteq \alpha X \sqcup \alpha Y$; $\forall Z \in
\mathfrak{B}: ((Z \sqsupseteq \alpha X \wedge Z \sqsupseteq \alpha Y)
\Rightarrow Z \sqsupseteq \alpha (X \sqcup Y))$; $\forall Z \in \mathfrak{B}:
((Z \sqsupseteq \alpha X \wedge Z \sqsupseteq \alpha Y) \Rightarrow \exists T
\in \mathfrak{A}: (T \sqsupseteq X \wedge T \sqsupseteq Y \wedge Z
\sqsupseteq \alpha T))$

(here $\sqsubseteq$ is our partial order).

The last formula does not use semi-lattice operation and is defined for every posets $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$.

Is this definition of "generalized semilattice morphism" known? What is its name? What are its properties? Where to read about it?